# Qual a origem e significado do termo «outros 500/quinhentos»?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, expressões-populares

Exemplo de uso:

> Costumo decorar antes de fazer uma prova, mas entender o assunto são
>   outros quinhentos

Qual o significado disto e qual a origem?

Comment: Isso tem a ver com os 500 anos do descobrimento do Brasil pelos portugueses

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado conforme o Randrade (fonte que ele encontrou) é provavel que se refira ao pagamento de injurias que para uma classe social era 300 soldos (soldo parece que era uma moeda antiga) e 500 soldos para outra classe. Se entendi quando alguém voltava a cometer uma injuria contra uma mesma pessoa ia reclamar que já tinha pago uma vez então na câmara se dizia, outra injuria outros 500. Mas ainda não pesquisei a fundo, só achei interessante deixar para sermos fontes de referencias quanto a este tipo de curiosidade, então depois eu confirmo. ;)

Comment: aqui tem uma fonte -> https://mundoestranho.abril.com.br/cultura/como-surgiu-a-expressao-outros-quinhentos/#

Comment: @Peixoto obrigado, foi a mesma historia que comentei acima. Agora só precisamos de uma resposta e fontes talvez para sustentar as afirmações.

Answer (score 2):

A expressão "outros quinhentos" significa "algo diferente", "outra história", "outra coisa" e é usada para enfatizar que, apesar de eventuais similaridades, os objetos da comparação são independentes.

Conforme já esclarecido nos comentários acima, [sua origem é provavelmente](http://guiadoscuriosos.uol.com.br/categorias/5735/1/de-onde-vem-a-expressao-outros-quinhentos.html) a indenização por injúria de 500 soldos (moeda antiga) a que nobres tinham direito na península ibérica da Idade Média, e ao entendimento jurídico de que injúrias distintas dariam direito à indenizações separadas ("quinhentos soldos pela primeira, *outros quinhentos* pela segunda").

Esse entendimento [é parcialmente baseado](https://mundoestranho.abril.com.br/cultura/como-surgiu-a-expressao-outros-quinhentos/#) em obras literárias, [sustentado](https://mundoestranho.abril.com.br/cultura/como-surgiu-a-expressao-outros-quinhentos/#) pelo etimologista Deonísio da Silva, da Universidade Federal de São Carlos e pelo autor Luis Câmara Cascudo, que [escreve](https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/de-onde-veio-a-expressao-outros-quinhentos/) em seu livro "Locuções Tradicionais no Brasil",

> Compreende-se que outra qualquer vilta, vitupério sem razão, posterior à multa cobrada, não seria incluída na primeira. Matéria para novo julgamento. Outra culpa. Outro dever. Seriam, evidentemente, outros quinhentos.

Essa versão também [foi divulgada](http://sic.sapo.pt/Programas/boatarde/2013-03-12-A-origem-das-expressoes-populares) (aos 1:34 do vídeo) pela rede de TV portuguesa [SIC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociedade_Independente_de_Comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o).